# $S_3$ in $Z_{18}$? Rings and subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

Let $a$ be an element in the ring $R$. Show that $S_a$ is a sub ring to $R$. What is $S_3$ in $Z_{18}$?

$$S_a=\begin{Bmatrix}
x\in R|xa=0
\end{Bmatrix}$$

My work:

$$x,y\in R\\ xa=0, ya=0\\ xa-ya=0\Rightarrow a(x-y)=0\Rightarrow x-y=0\\
a(xy)=(ax)y=0$$
$S_a$ is a sub ring to R.

Does this hold, or have I completely misunderstood it?

How can I continue with $S_3$ in $Z_{18}$?

EDIT:
What is $S_3$ in $Z_{18}$?

$$S_3=\begin{Bmatrix}
x\in R|3x=0
\end{Bmatrix}\\?$$

Comment: You've extended the question since it was asked. There are 18 elements in $Z_{18}$. Is it so hard to check which ones satisfy $3x=0$?

Comment: I did not understand what the task asked for. Felt too simple if it asked which element in $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ satisfy $3x=0$. But i got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion $xa−ya=0⇒(x−y)a=0⇒x−y=0$ only holds if $a$ is not a zero divisor of $R$.

But you don't need to go that far: Let $xa=0$ and $ya=0$. Then $0 = xa-ya = (x-y)a$ and so $x-y\in S_a$.

So $S_a$ is indeed a subring of $R$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know how i can proceed with "What is S3 in Z18?"? What is it asking?